# Failed to insert data into table using insert select query

Tags: hive

I am attempting to insert data into table i am getting the following error:

```
hive>CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employee
(
EMP_ID BIGINT,
EMP_DESG STRING,
EMP_ADD ARRAY<STRUCT<DNO: STRING,STATE:STRING,CITY:STRING,ZIPCODE:BIGINT>>
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
   stored as textfile;
;

 hive>insert overwrite table empmongo 
     select emp_id, emo_desg, emp_add from employee;
```

> FAILED: NoMatchingMethodException No matching method for class
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFToString with
>   (array>).
>   Possible choices: *FUNC*(binary)  *FUNC*(float)  *FUNC*(double) 
>   *FUNC*(string)  *FUNC*(timestamp)  *FUNC*(decimal)  *FUNC*(bigint)  *FUNC*(void)  *FUNC*(boolean)  *FUNC*(int)  *FUNC*(smallint)  *FUNC*(tinyint)

can you please provide a suggested solution?

Answer (score -1):

I was able to insert data into your table two different ways:

```
insert into table employee2 select * from employee;
```

Works fine:

Also:

```
insert into table employee2 select  emp_id, emp_desg, emp_add from employee;
```

works fine

Here is the output :

```
hive> select * from employee2;
OK
emp_id  emp_desg    emp_add
123 HiThere [{"dno":"Emp_Desg","state":null,"city":null,"zipcode":null}]
123 HiThere [{"dno":"Emp_Desg","state":null,"city":null,"zipcode":null}]
Time taken: 0.083 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
```